# Will image work on a web after extension rename?

Tags: image, web

Our junior dev was asked to change .png to .jpg and he just changed the extension. He didn't use any program to convert it to .jpg and cut down the size.

I assume, he's been doing it whole time, as he said, the converting and compression is something new to him.

My concern is, if it's gonna work on websites (only websites), across browsers and OS's and devices. I don't care (at this stage) about size, just if all browsers are smart enough to serve the user an image and not to lock down somehow, because the image has different extension name and compression method used.